# How to make windows boot off 1 drive

Tags: windows-10, partitioning

I have installed windows 10 profressional onto an SSD.

I have a problem, in that the installation seems to have used one of my other hard drives for the system reserve partition you can see in the screenshot.

What is this partition for, I am thinking I could do one of the following,

- Move it to the SSD
- Backup that partition, reformat the drive it is on to be GPT, then put it back

I wouldn't be bothered about it except that I cannot use the unallocated space on the drive. Clicking on the unallocated space to create a partition, all the options are greyed out.

I think this is because the drive uses a MBR rather than a GPT.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I have it sorted now. I found this,

https://www.sevenforums.com/installation-setup/189387-system-reserved-partition-wrong-drive-how-do-i-move.html

And performed a similar set of steps as mentioned in the first post, Bill2,

```
1) Open a command prompt as admin, then type the following:

bcdboot C:\windows /s C:

Hit Enter. 

This command places boot files on the C: partition which is your windows.

2) Now open disk management, right click C: and click Mark active. Right 
click System reserved and click Mark Inactive (unless its already showing 
inactive).

Reboot. Once all this is successfully completed, use partition wizard boot 
cd to delete system reserved and pull E: to the left to use up all the space 
on the disk.
```